# Android AppWidget - Communicating between two ListViews

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

So, I am writing an Android app that manages collections of assets.  I am trying to write an AppWiget such that the widget contains two ListViews, one representing a list of the collections and one representing the assets in the currently selected list.  I created an AppWidgetProvider and two RemoteViewsService/RemoteViewServicesFactory, one for each ListView.

When the collections ListView is clicked, it creates a Bundle and passes collection_id back to the Provider.  Now at this point, I need to call notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged on the asset ListView to let to it know to refresh, but I also would like to pass this collection_id to it so it knows what data to fetch (out of a local mySql db).

Is there a mechanism that allows for this?  The only thing I can can think of or find is to store the current collection_id in the database or SharedPreferences, but it seems a bit hacky.   Does anyone know of something more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the id to the intent triggered by the click on the first listview? In your first `RemoteViewServicesFactory`:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt("ID", id);
Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_item, fillInIntent);
```

then in your second `RemoteViewServicesFactory`, you'll read it like so:

```
Int id = extras.getInt("ID");
```